# Forcing a selected answer for those absent users

Tags: discussion

So, the "community" pushes questions to the top that are ancient which do not have a selected answer.

Could moderators select an accepted answer to remove these questions from the top - if people need the information they should be searching anyway so it won't mean we loose the information.

As an example (one of many you can find), see this question, has one answer and the author of the question is very absent...

[mechanics of materials Mohr](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/17966/10902)

Comment: I'm completely agree. It would be useful if the system sends those users a notification if at least one of the answers receive more than two upvote after a specific periode of time. In our community all the moderators are civil engineers so it wouldn't be very wise if they have the authority to choose an answer. Many questions are out of their area of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I agree that this is annoying. I have resigned myself to viewing this as a way to get newer users to view older questions.

Second, mods don't have this power. Selecting an answer is solely up to the original user.

This has been asked a few times in a few different ways on Meta.Stackexchange:

- [Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8692/282289)
- [Encourage users to select 'Accepted Answer' for old Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10672/282289)
- [Community vote for "Accepted Answer" (Rep. >= 5000 only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/community-vote-for-accepted-answer-rep-5000-only/8617#8617)

The general response from the Stackexchange employees is that this is not an issue that they want to address.

Also, I think that the "community" user stops bringing up old questions once there are highly voted answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ah well I’m not the only one then!